# Canon iP3000 Printer not working after using with OS X Lion

Tags: macos, printing

I was able for some time to print from Lion using a 10.6 driver. Recently I got a 5 yellow light blink error sign which is the sign for a print head problem.

- I installed a new print head without result (same error message).
- I opened a brand new Canon iP3000 printer. It printed one copy and then it had the same error message (it now will not print on any printer).
- My son brought over a working used iP3000. It printed one copy and it now has the same error message and will no longer work at all.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Apple does not provide a driver for this printer so it may be due to the fact of an outdated driver

> It now will not print on any printer

The fact that you say that however leads me to believe that you may have an issue with the USB port in your Mac, if you can try it in all the USB ports on your Mac and see if you still have the same issue. If you do then you may need to contact an Apple Genius to see if they are aware of this issue and a resolution to it